# Linq How to group joined queries

Tags: linq

I am newbee and can join two datasets. I want to group these by OrderNo query. How can I manage that?

```
var result = context.Order
               .Join(context.OrderDetails
               , od => od.OrderId
               , o => o.OrderId
               , (o, od) => new {  
                       o.OrderNo, od.ProductName, o.OrderDate  
                })  
                .Select(s => s);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 var result = context.Order
                   .Join(context.OrderDetails
                   , od => od.OrderId
                   , o => o.OrderId
                   , (o, od) => new {  
                           o.OrderNo, od.ProductName, o.OrderDate  
                    })  
                    .GroupBy(p => new{
                          o.OrderNo
                    })
     
                    .Select(s => s);
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot.